# Typescript error: Property 'classes' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to using Typescript and getting the following error:

```
Property 'classes' is missing in type '{ title: string; text: string; industry: string; location: string; image: string; date: string; link: string; }' but required in type 'CaseStudyCardProps'
```

I'm using `react-jss` for component styles, and wondering if there's a clash happening with the styles object vs passing the classes prop itself.

**App.tsx**

```
import CaseStudyCard from './components/CaseStudyCard'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CaseStudyCard 
        title="Preparing organizations for the future"
        text="This is the body of the card and should wrap continuously" 
        industry="Healthcare" 
        location="Nowheresville" 
        image="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/600x400"  
        date="March 22nd 2021"
        link="https://www.google.com"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**CaseStudyCard.tsx**

```
const CardHeader = ({classes, image}) => {
     const style = { 
              backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
          };
          return (
            <header style={style} className={classes.cardHeader}>
              <h4 className={classes.cardHeader}>News</h4>
            </header>
          )
      }

const Button = ({classes, link}) => (
     <a href={link} className={classes.buttonPrimary}>
              Find out more
     </a>   
)
      
const CardBody = ({classes, date, title, text, link}) => {
      return (
        <div className={classes.cardBody}>
          <p className={classes.date}>{date}</p>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p className={classes.bodyContent}>{text}</p>
          <Button classes={classes} link={link}/>
        </div>
      )
}

interface CaseStudyCardProps {
       image: string,
       classes: object,
       title: string,
       date: string,
       location: string,
       industry: string,
       link: string,
       text: string
     } 
      export default function CaseStudyCard (props: CaseStudyCardProps) {
        const classes = useStyles()
        return (
            <div className={classes.card}>
              <CardHeader classes={props.classes} image={props.image}/>
              <CardBody 
                classes={props.classes} 
                title={props.title} 
                date={props.date}
                location={props.location}
                industry={props.industry}
                link={props.link}
                text={props.text}
              />
            </div>
          )
      }
```

Comment: Just remove classes from the interface?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have a classes field here:

```
  <CaseStudyCard 
    title="Preparing organizations for the future"
    text="This is the body of the card and should wrap continuously" 
    industry="Healthcare" 
    location="Nowheresville" 
    image="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/600x400"  
    date="March 22nd 2021"
    link="https://www.google.com"
  />
```

When you create a Typescript interface and put fields, Typescript will throw an error if you don't include that field.

#### Option 1

Make classes field optional:

```
interface CaseStudyCardProps {
       image: string,
       classes?: object,
       title: string,
       date: string,
       location: string,
       industry: string,
       link: string,
       text: string
     }
```

#### Option 2

Remove the classes field from the interface. (Be careful with this, as if some of your `CaseStudyCard` instances receives a classes field, then Typescript will won't recognize that and throw an error)

```
interface CaseStudyCardProps {
       image: string,
       title: string,
       date: string,
       location: string,
       industry: string,
       link: string,
       text: string
     }
```

#### Option 3

Give classes field to the object. (If you are doing this make sure you add accurate conditionals not to potentially get `Can not access x field of undefined` errors )

```
 <CaseStudyCard 
    title="Preparing organizations for the future"
    text="This is the body of the card and should wrap continuously" 
    industry="Healthcare" 
    location="Nowheresville" 
    image="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/600x400"  
    date="March 22nd 2021"
    link="https://www.google.com"
    classes={}
  />
```

Edit: When your `classes` object's existence is not 100%, you have to add conditionals accordingly. For instance, you are using classes inside the `CardBody`

```
const CardBody = ({classes, date, title, text, link}) => {
      return (
        <div className={classes.cardBody}>
          <p className={classes.date}>{date}</p>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p className={classes.bodyContent}>{text}</p>
          <Button classes={classes} link={link}/>
        </div>
      )
}
```

However, you don't have the `classes` or your `classes` is empty. In this case, you have to add an if check to avoid problems:

```
const CardBody = ({classes, date, title, text, link}) => {
      return classes && Object.keys(classes).length > 0 ? (
        <div className={classes.cardBody}>
          <p className={classes.date}>{date}</p>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p className={classes.bodyContent}>{text}</p>
          <Button classes={classes} link={link}/>
        </div>
      ) : null
}
```

Or, more logically, don't even render `CardBody` when your classes object is empty:

```
  {Object.keys(props.classes).length > 0 && <CardBody 
        classes={props.classes} 
        title={props.title} 
        date={props.date}
        location={props.location}
        industry={props.industry}
        link={props.link}
        text={props.text}
      />}
```

And likewise, in `CardHeader` you use `classes` to render a JSX element. Don't render `CardHeader` if your classes is going to be empty. Or make sure you have your `classes` object 100%.

Comment: By either removing it or setting `classes?: object`, I get the error: `Binding element 'classes' implicitly has an 'any' type.` when importing classes as a prop in `const CardHeader = ({classes, image}) => {...}`

Comment: You have to decide based on your condition, if you destructure `classes` like that, you need to keep it in the interface and pass some dummy object when you don't need it. Like option 3.

Comment: By providing `classes?: object` and and empty classes prop `classes={}`, I get `JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression`

Comment: When you define an interface, you are saying typescript that, when you see a variable of this type, these are going to be the fields. Now, some fields can exist or not, in which case you do like `classes?: object`. If that is the case, before destructuring it you can add an if check `if(props.hasOwnProperty("classes")) classes = props.classes`. So, bascially you got to decide and structure your dependent code accordingly. Or you can add a check to see if classes is empty, before rendering it as a JSX element

Comment: Maybe it's the lack of coffee yet, but I've used the `classes?: object` logic, and trying to figure out where I'd use the check if the classes property exist, but still getting the error `JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression`

Comment: I am guessing you use the classes in <CardBody component. Can you edit your question to include the `CardBody` code? And I will edit my answer to try explaining more clearly :)

Comment: I've updated the question with full code. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my code with your recommendations, but regardless I still get the error `JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression` because of the empty object with `classes={}` in `<CaseStudyCard />` in `App.tsx`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why that happens, then.

Comment: Thanks for the help.